# When do we use and when do we not use an indefinite article in front of the noun “job”?

Tags: grammar, articles, questions

Can anybody explain why we use and do not use an indefinite article in front of the noun “job”?

Examples:

> 1. It is **a job** he desired all his life.

> 2. What **job** would you like to do?

Is it because the sentence is interrogative?

Comment: Because [that's how](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/questions-wh-questions) you formulate questions with *what*, *which*, or *whose*. (Not sure what else there is to say, maybe this belongs on English Language Learners.)

Comment: What **is a job** that you would like to do? There you have the article. So it's okay.

Comment: As @StuartF suggests, whether to use *a* in your pair of examples has nothing to do with the word *job*. That word is in no way special in this regard.

Answer (score 1):

*Which* and *what* are [determiners](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determiner), and they cannot normally be combined with other determiners such as articles.

The only context in which *what a job* might appear is in the exclamation "What a job!", where "What" has a different meaning and different grammar.

(I am not talking about sentences in which the sequence of words *what a job* occurs but does not form a grammatical unit, Such as "What a job like this needs is time.")